# Php "errors" on registration form

Tags: php, regex

Hey guys I'm having a bit of a problem not getting my errors to show on my form. This is the code Im running live (just testing it on my hosting site) and it's not showing anything when I put things into the test field. Any idea as to what might be wrong?

```
<?php

    if ($_POST['submit']) {

      if (!$_POST['email']) $error.="Please enter your email!";
        else if !(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $error.="Uh Uh uh, you didn't enter a valid email address!";

    if (!$_POST['password']) $error.="Please enter a password!";
        else {

         if (strlen($_POST['password'])<8) $error.="Please enter a password of at least 8 characters.";
        if (!preg_match('`[A-Z]`',$_POST['password'])) $error.="Please include at least one capital letter in your password."

        }

    if ($error) echo "There were error(s) in your sign up details:".$error;
    }


?>


<form method="post">

    <input type ="email" name="email" id="email" />

    <input type ="password" name="password" />

    <input type ="submit" name="submit" value ="Click for Cookies" />

</form>
```

Comment: There are many things to say, but before all indent your code in a logical way (take a look about PSR recommendations if you have no ideas about how you can write a well-formatted code). To know if an array item exists or not, please don't write `if ($_POST['thing'])` but use `isset`, example: `if (isset($_POST['thing']))` and check the value after if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to echo what @Casmir said in the comments about using isset, but have you tried submitting something incorrect and then simply viewed the page source?  When you do, is the text there?

If it isn't then your test conditionals and possible the conditional looking for an error are incorrect, try using isset on the $error variable as well.

One more thing, you said this is on a hosting site, make sure you have display_error set to On via a local php.ini file (or however your hoster supports custom PHP config values) to make sure there aren't code errors preventing the execution from completing either which would be hidden via 'production level' settings (Also remove them when finished testing of course!).

Comment: I really appreciate the help, however I found out there wasn’t anything wrong with the code to begin with. Turns out my host (iPage) despite showing that it’s php being configured correctly, isn’t running any of the php code. I put even the most simple of php code in there, and it’s not working. So I’ve spent the better part of a week trying to deal with the wrong problem. Now I have to figure out what’s wrong with my host.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is incorrect as you are checking for **!$_POST[email]**, because you will get it every time all you need is to check for **is_empty($_POST[email])**, if it is you can echo "not allowed empty" or something, and if not empty, you can place regex to check for valid email id.